# jquery-steps : disable submit button when form are submited

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I'm using jquery-steps.js ,

I want to disable submit button when some one click on submit, and never activate it until the the form is submitted.

The reason way is that if some one click on submit many time the I receive many mails!

Note : my HTML file does not include submit button , it is only show from the js file that I include bellow

and my js file look like this.

```
$(function() {
    $("#smart-form").steps( {
        bodyTag:"fieldset", headerTag:"h2", bodyTag:"fieldset", transitionEffect:"slideLeft", titleTemplate:"<span class='number'>#index#</span> #title#", labels: {
            finish: "Send søknad", next: "Neste", previous: "Tilbake", loading: "Laster..."
        }
        , onStepChanging:function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            if(currentIndex>newIndex) {
                return true;
            }
            var form=$(this);
            if(currentIndex<newIndex) {}
            return form.valid();
        }
        , onStepChanged:function(event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {}
        , onFinishing:function(event, currentIndex) {
            var form=$(this);
            form.validate().settings.ignore=":disabled";
            return form.valid();
        }
        , onFinished:function(event, currentIndex) {
            var form=$(this);
            $(form).ajaxSubmit( {
                target:'.result', beforeSubmit:function() {}
                , error:function() {}
                , success:function() {
                    $('.alert-success').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
                    $('.field').removeClass("state-error, state-success");
                    if($('.alert-error').length==0) {
                        $('#smart-form').resetForm();
                        reloadCaptcha();
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your html may not include the submit button but you can select it by using jquery selectors and knowing the parent element

Comment: thanks , How to do that ?

Comment: On your page, right click on the submit button (or an area near it) and do inspect element.  This will pop up the developer window and will navigate to a container nearby.  You can look at the ids from there.  If you need help, paste what you see surrounding the submit button

Comment: <a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Send søknad</a> 
here is it

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit generic (and I haven't tested it) but that can get you started

```
$(document).find('input[type="submit"').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first line `$(function() {`, add :

```
var isFinishing = false;
```

In the `onFinished` event change this line :

```
var form=$(this);
```

for :

```
if (isFinishing) return;

isFinishing = true;
var form=$(this);
```

If the `success` event of the AJAX call isn't reloading the page, you shall consider adding this line within this function :

```
isFinishing = false;
```

Comment: Maybe the "button" is not a button. Can you inspect this "submit button" and check what is its HTML ?

Comment: the button is generated on js file not on html, i can not see it on html file , how ever when I do inspect element i get this  
<a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Send søknad</a>

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll change the answer.

Comment: I'm sad to tell you that is not working, 
now I cannot move to the final step to see the submit button 
I'm really thankful for your reply

Comment: Can you update your code so I can see what you have did ? Or even better, can you create a jsFiddle so I can work with it ?